# simple html dom parser to get class id

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

i am trying to use simple html dom parser to get this following data

```
<input type=submit value="Change Password" class="button">
```

i would like it to get the value `Change password`

and issue and `if else statement`

so if change password found

`echo Ready`

and if not found echo

Not Ready

i am new to using `simple html dom` and would love some kind remember to help me

i understand i have to start my simple html as follows but how can i do the above

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://example.com');


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
<?php 

include "simple_html_dom.php";
$html = file_get_html("http://example.com");

if ($html->find("input[value=Change Password]", 0)) {
    echo "Ready";
} else {
    echo "Not ready";
}
```

Comment: there are many more input fields in the source so can this still help ?

Comment: Is this the only field that could have 'Change password'?

Comment: Updated my answer with a simple method :)

Comment: thnaks bro can u help me a little more heres my my old dom document if else script what do i need to do to remove old domdocument stuff and use your simple html dom statement heres the link to code http://pastebin.com/tbxA99ie

Comment: Try this: remove lines 9 to 12, add this `$title = $html->find("title", 0)->plaintext;`

Comment: okay so i edited the script as follow bro http://pastebin.com/a3DiaCtT somehow i think thats wrong also i still want it to find Change Password like mention at the start of this qeustion thanks for your help and support

Comment: No problem. It's weird that you assign `$html` to one thing, and then immediately to another. Either store these two in different variables, or process one, then process the other using the same variable. Meaning: `$html = file_get_html("example.com"); // process it, $html = checkemail($email, password); // process that`

Comment: okay so i dont really need to process it twice so ill remove that line also how can i correct the if else statments to change passpord like u shown me on the answer i bassically want you answer swapped in domdocuments place

Comment: Check this out: http://pastebin.com/CRM0hL6y You can then manipulate the two variables `$title` and `$checkPassword` as you like with `if` statements.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29059/discussion-between-david-tuckwell-and-marcinkonys)